# How do I auto layout constraints when I add a new view such as a error message to the top of a main view

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is my controller as it loaded

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mainTitleText];
    [self.view addSubview:self.subTitle];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.acceptBtn];
    [self.view addSubview:self.notAcceptBtn];

   [self addConstraints];
}
```

I add my constraints here

```
- (void)addConstraints {
    id metrics = @{ @"textHMargin": @10, @"topMargin": @110, @"margin": @8, @"titleHeight": @60, @"subtitleHeight": @40, @"tableHeight": @88 };

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-textHMargin-[mainTitleText]-textHMargin-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-textHMargin-[subTitle]-textHMargin-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-margin-[acceptBtn]-margin-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-margin-[notAcceptBtn]-margin-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-topMargin-[mainTitleText(titleHeight)]-margin-[subTitle(subtitleHeight)]-[tableView(tableHeight)]-margin-[acceptBtn]-margin-[notAcceptBtn]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];

}
```

This is where I'm getting stuck. When I add my error message view it does not stack on top and push everything down.

```
- (void)acceptAction:(id)sender {
    [self.activeTextfield resignFirstResponder];

    if (self.airlineInfo.flightNumber && self.airlineInfo.airlineDescription) {
        //TODO: success code
    } else {
    //show error
           id metrics = @{ @"textHMargin": @10, @"topMargin": @110, @"margin": @8, @"titleHeight": @60, @"subtitleHeight": @40, @"tableHeight": @88 };
        [self.view addSubview:self.infoMessage];
          [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-textHMargin-[infoMessage]-textHMargin-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];

         [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-topMargin-[infoMessage(20)]-margin-[mainTitleText(titleHeight)]-margin-[subTitle(subtitleHeight)]-[tableView(tableHeight)]-margin-[acceptBtn]-margin-[notAcceptBtn]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];
    }
}
```

[view http://kgaddy.com/errorView.jpg](http://kgaddy.com/errorView.jpg).

Comment: At least some of the constraints installed by addConstraints might need to be removed when adding the error message view. Or is that code not posted?

Comment: I think that is what my question is. How do I remove or update the constraints?

Comment: Oh, ok. First though, could you post a screenshot of the UI before the error message view is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is not use constraints for this extra view at all. Just stick it into the interface. But change the `constant` on your existing top view to a larger value, thus pushing it down and pushing down everything that is pinned to it below it.

So, right now, you are saying:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-topMargin-[mainTitleText(titleHeight)]-margin-[subTitle(subtitleHeight)]-[tableView(tableHeight)]-margin-[acceptBtn]-margin-[notAcceptBtn]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];
```

Instead of just adding those constraints directly, first keep a reference to them; then add them. That way you can sneakily remove those constraints later! Then you do the same thing again but with a push-down value at the top:

```
[self.view removeConstraints:self.verticalContraints]; // previously saved
self.verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(40)-topMargin-[mainTitleText(titleHeight)]-margin-[subTitle(subtitleHeight)]-[tableView(tableHeight)]-margin-[acceptBtn]-margin-[notAcceptBtn]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:self.views]];
[self.view addConstraints:self.verticalConstraints];
```

Notice the "40" that I snuck in there. You can fix that to a better value experimentally. You see from this how to swap out a bunch of constraints and put a different set in their place.

Comment: Cool-o-rama! The simple trick of keeping a reference to a constraint or set of constraints as you create it and put it into the interface, so that you can later swap constraints in and out, is very easy and very, very powerful. - It is true that we've cheated by not inserting your alert view into the sequence, but in fact that is only a minor modification of what I've given. You would then have one set of constraints for when the alert view is present and another for when it isn't.